# Deriving a unique derivative operator with torsion such that $\triangledown g = 0$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, general-relativity, special-relativity

From Wald's General Relativity, Chapter 3 problem 1c), in the solution from http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~dcross/papers/wald.pdf:

$\triangledown g = 0$ becomes again

$$\triangledown_a g_{bc} = \bar{\triangledown}_ag_{bc} - C^d_{ab}g_{dc}- C^d_{ac}g_{bd} = \bar{\triangledown}_ag_{bc} - C_{cab}-C_{bac}$$

If we add the permutation (ab) and subtract the permutation (cab) as before we get

$$\bar{\triangledown}_a g_{bc} + \bar{\triangledown}_ag_{bc} -  \bar{\triangledown}_ag_{bc} =  T_{bac}-T_{abc}+2C_{c(ab)}$$

How have we gone form C's to T's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that *the torsion in basically the antisymmetric part of $C$*

$$
T_{abc} = C_{a[bc]} \tag{1}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
\color{blue}{C_{bac} - C_{bca}} &=& \color{blue}{C_{b[ac]} = T_{bac}} \\
\color{red}{C_{abc} - C_{acb}} &=& \color{red}{C_{a[bc]} = T_{abc}}  \\
\color{magenta}{C_{cab} + C_{cba}} &=& \color{magenta}{2C_{c(ba)}}  \tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

With this in mind ($\nabla g = 0$)

\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{\nabla}_ag_{bc} + \tilde{\nabla}_bg_{ac} - \tilde{\nabla}_cg_{ab} &=& [\nabla_a g_{bc} + C_{cab} + C_{bac}] + [\nabla_{b}g_{ac} + C_{cba} + C_{abc}] \\
&& -[\nabla_cg_{ab} + C_{bca} + C_{abc}] \\
&=& (\color{magenta}{C_{cab} + C_{cba}}) + \color{blue}{C_{bac} - C_{bca}} + (\color{red}{C_{abc} - C_{acb}}) \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}& \color{magenta}{2C_{c(ba)}} + \color{blue}{C_{b[ac]}} + \color{red}{C_{a[bc]}} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \color{magenta}{2C_{c(ab)}} + \color{blue}{T_{bac}} + \color{red}{T_{abc}}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Ill have another look but I think statement is the bit im not seeing

Comment: Yeah I cant see how (1) is so obvious to you

Comment: @Permian It is actually in the solution you attach: Problem 1a. I assumed since you were asking about part c, you already solved part a

Comment: where are the C's in 1a)?

Comment: @Permian Page 7, *a) We note that ...*

Comment: Ill have a think about this tomorrow

Comment: Yeah I really cant see how a) we note that.... bit helps at all

Comment: @Permian Problem 1a is exactly to show that $T_{abc} = C_{a[bc]}$

Comment: how are you going from $\triangledown_a\triangledown_b f - \triangledown_b\triangledown_a f = -T_{ab}^c\triangledown_c f$ to $C_{a[bc]}$?

Comment: @Permian I see, your question is then what is the meaning of $T^a_{bc}$, is that correct? I believe this may be worth posting a separate question

Comment: im ok @caverac, just starting my study of GR and struggling with the differential geometry in it

Comment: It is a very fascinating subject, congratulations!